# I can't find the place to ask my question

Tags: support

I have a question about my Cross Validated post: [I have a question I want to ask but I can't find the appropriate place to ask it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374470/i-have-a-question-i-want-to-ask-but-i-cant-find-the-appropriate-place-to-ask-it)

Is this a statistics question or something else? What tags should it have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "What is the percentage of direct workers in an automotive production
>   plant compared to all the employees?"

- **All of stackexchange** This question is too broad to be asked on any stackexchange website. The term (an automotive production plant) is too general and ambiguous. Automotive production plants are not all the same, thus without further defining the aim of the question or the context, it is not possible to give a conclusive answer (which 'automotive production plant' are we talking about?).

  You would be better off searching in databases of scientific articles. E.g you could use: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=manufacturing+overhead+automotive

  where the second hit (in my case) gives an article with loads of information (it looks like roughly two thirds of the labor is direct labor).

  [ITTNER, C.D. and MACDUFFIE, J.P., 1995. Explaining plant‐level differences in manufacturing overhead: Structural and executional cost drivers in the world auto industry. Production and Operations Management, 4(4), pp.312-334.](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1937-5956.1995.tb00297.x)

  or you look further to get to something that fills your (unclear) needs.
- **Economics** If you would be able to better specify your question then I *guess* that this question fits 'accounting' or 'management'.  Note that you can not ask this on the economics site (which would be most close) see [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

  > Accounting is a separate discipline, and there is no StackExchange site dedicated to that matter yet.

  You might be able to frame it as business economics, but it really depends on what the context of your question is. If you explain the context of the question better then it will also be easier to see if there is a stackexchange site where the question might fit.

---

By the way, you have got an interesting stackexchange history for this question with a lot of iterations of phrases like *"don't post on this site $x_n$ go to $x_{n+1}$"*

- **[Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/60341/what-is-the-percentage-of-direct-workers-in-an-automotive-production-plant-compa)**

  > This is not about vehicle maintenance or repair, consider trying the workplace stack
- [**The workplace**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/121730/what-is-the-percentage-of-direct-workers-in-an-automotive-production-plant-compa)

  > I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about navigating the workplace as explained in the help center
- **[Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24421/what-is-the-percentage-of-direct-workers-in-an-automotive-production-plant-compa)**

  > I see that you are having troubles finding a good place to ask this question, it seems as if no community is for for it. Maybe you can ask where to ask on the stackexchange meta: meta.stackexchange.com/questions.
- **[meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317444/i-have-a-question-i-want-to-ask-but-i-cant-find-the-appropriate-place-to-ask-it)**

  > I think you ought to modify the title, Meta is getting a lot of off-topic question that should be posted on Maths, SO, SU, etc. and
  >   this title looks like a ruse to bypass inspection. Saying that,
  >   wouldn't something connected with statistics be the place you're
  >   looking for? stats.stackexchange.com (Cross Validated) try posting on
  >   their meta page for guidance.
- [**cross-validated**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374470/i-have-a-question-i-want-to-ask-but-i-cant-find-the-appropriate-place-to-ask-it)

  > CV Meta is for issues arising in the use of CV, not for asking where else you might ask a question.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, your question is not appropriate for this site.  It seems to be about statistics in the sense of baseball statistics, that is, some number that is pertinent to describing or understanding some phenomenon.  In the sense used on this site, [statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics) has to do with *analyses* of data in the service of some goal.  The key distinction here is that you want to get an actual number, whereas this site is for people wanting to know what they should do with the numbers they already have.

I don't know if there is any SE site that is appropriate for your question.  There is a site for people seeking data ([open data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)) that might be able to help you find that information; there is also a site for questions about [economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) that might have information to the extent that how much of the workforce in different industries would be what you call 'direct workers' might be a research topic in economics; similarly, there is a [quantitative finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) site, and investors might care about the proportions of direct workers in different industries to help them make investment decisions; but I couldn't be confident any of those would think your question is a good fit.  Some [library / internet] 'shoe leather' research might be needed to track that information down.